# What is the syntax to update employee address using API call for Quickbooks Online on Postman?

Tags: postman, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have successfully done an API call from Quickbooks Online that shows me a list of employees through Get https://{{baseurl}}/v3/company/{{companyId}}/query?query=Select * from Employee.

I wanted to find out what the syntax was to update employee addresses using an API call. I am new to all the lingo, but I would love to learn, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all you need in the documentation:

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/employee#full-update-an-employee

Comment: Thank you! I reviewed the link and I believe I have found what I was looking for.